# How to have english and greek characters in MySQL WorkBench?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

In a column in mySql Workbench, which is of text type, i want to have both greek and english characters. I have set UTF-8 default collation, but all greek characters are question marks. Any idea?
(Searching about this, someone who had the same problem said that when he tried this on windows everything was ok. He was using mac os x and so do i. Could this be the reason?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be good if you could amend your question with an image, but I guess it's just a matter of the proper font. Look in the preferences and select a font that includes the language script you want to use (e.g. using a good Unicode font will mostly cover that, e.g. Arial Unicode, Bitstream Cyberbit and others).